# What is the difference between the H and B poles in vertical coffins?

Tags: latex3, xcoffins

In the `xcoffins` documentation the `H` and `B` poles are described as follows.

> `H` a pole running along the baseline of the typeset material contained in the coﬃn.
>
> `B` a pole running along the baseline of the material at the bottom of the coﬃn.

However, the baseline `H` of a vertical coffin (created with `\SetVerticalCoffin`) seems to always be the baseline of the last line in that coffin, i.e. `B`. In fact, `B` is not even shown by `\DisplayCoffinHandles`, as can be seen in figure 1 of that document.

So, is `B` ever different from `H`? If not, what is the point of having both names?

Comment: No idea whether there can be a difference, but `B` is more intuitive than `H` for the position of the handle, so having both names makes sense :)

Comment: The baseline that TeX 'sees' doesn't have to be the base of the coffin

Answer (score 5):

They can differ if you join coffins:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

% Adding a pole to a rotated coffin:
\NewCoffin\TestCoffinA
\NewCoffin\TestCoffinB
\SetVerticalCoffin\TestCoffinA{1cm}{y\\y}
\SetVerticalCoffin\TestCoffinB{1cm}{x\\x\\x}
\JoinCoffins\TestCoffinA[T,r]\TestCoffinB[T,l]
\MarkCoffinHandle \TestCoffinA
[ B,l ] {green}
\MarkCoffinHandle \TestCoffinA
[ H,l ] {green}

\TypesetCoffin\TestCoffinA

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JosephWright seems to me that given Ulrike's example we could perhaps improve on the documentation :-)